# Golang Test return EOF through VsCode button

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Environment:

- VSCode 1.68.0
- Golang 1.18

Question:

1. I write some golang code with net/http.
2. I write some test code for step 1.
3. When I use Button "run test" in vscode. It returns error about http EOF.
   [image]

[image]
But if I use the same cmd in tty, it will be OK. Why?
[image]

My colleagues are OK with the same code.

I will be grateful if you can help me.